# express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option Server is running at http://localhost:undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs, express-session

I have an XAMPP MySQL & Apache servers running locally to try and host my build at port:3306. I have gotten past the ECONNREFUSED error & now I'm presented with the Express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option issue. Even though the session secret is defined in the Server.js

Server.js session secret code:

```
  app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

That means `process.env.SESSION_SECRET` evaluates to a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: I've defined it in a .env file but it still says localhost undefined.

Comment: Do you expect Node.js to read that file automatically? Because it won't, you need a module like [`dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to do that.